# Is this error related to sfDoctrinePlugin or Symfony? How can I fix this?

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony1, doctrine

I have a project created using Symfony 1.4.15. Because I like Doctrine :) I created a admin module using the command: "doctrine:generate-admin". All works fine when I "save & add" but when I "save" only I get this error:

> 500 | Internal Server Error | Doctrine_Record_UnknownPropertyException | 
>   Unknown record property / related component "name" on "Ncargo"

and I not know how to fix this, any help on this? This happen with all the modules generated by doctrine:generate-admin task.

Cheers and thanks in advance

Comment: You should maybe be add the whole stack trace to your answer, not just the error message.

Comment: Here you got the entire stack trace http://pastebin.com/bDPd0PR8 (posted in pastebin because here I can't or I not know how to)

Comment: As you can see `getName()` is called here: `in SF_ROOT_DIR\cache\backend\dev\modules\autoNcargo\templates\editSuccess.php`
I think you should implement this method for your `Ncargo` model. What is a bit strange is they should call the `__toString()` method. Maybe you should file a bug.

Comment: Then what's your recommendation? Did you mean that this is this a Symfony bug or a Doctrine bug?

Comment: My recommendation : try implementing `getName()`. I think it might be an sf bug (the admin generator is a part of sf). If you see no reference to this getName method in the documentation of the admin generator, then there is a bug (at least not documenting this)

Comment: Fine but what getName() method should return? I have implemented `public function __toString() { return $this->getDescripcion(); }` but not ideas what getName() should return also there is not 'name' parameter in the schema and also the DB

Comment: returning `(string) $this` should do, I think

Comment: Also, maybe showing the content of this editSuccess.php file would help understanding the purpose of this call to `getName()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I would recommand to:

rebuild the model classes: `./symfony doctrine:build --all-classes`

clear the cache: `./symfony cc`

What's happend here is that Doctrine think there is a "name" field on your model.

You should also send us your generator.yml, have you set any "name" in it? Send us your model too.

Comment: I do this a lot of times with no results and the generator for this module is this http://pastebin.com/5NiNyeRR and after check the generator I finally found the mistake **title: Editando rol "%%name%%"** where name should be **descripcion** (which is the field in my table), anyway thanks to both of you